# Determine 2 vectors so that a condition holds

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image: The problem]

> Determine the vectors $\hat u+\hat v$ so that
>   $$\hat u+\hat v=u$$
>   $$2\hat u+3\hat v=v$$
>   are true.

I tried:
$$\hat{u} + \hat{v} = (1,0)$$
$$2\hat{u} + 3\hat{v} = (0,1)$$
$$(a,b) + (c,d) = (1,0)$$
$$2(a,b) + 3(c,d) = (0,1)$$
$$a + c = 1$$
$$b + d = 0$$
$$2a + 3c = 0$$
$$b + d = 1$$

This is obviously not true since $b+d$ cannot both equal 1 and 0 at the same time. Why does my solution not work and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

When we multiply a vector by a scalar number, like in $2(a,b)$, we have to multiply *each coordinate*, so we get $(2a,2b)$ and not $(2a,b)$.

Thus, your last equation should rather be $2b+3d=1$.